# Springboot maven plugin to build and deploy images to gitlab is showing published 42 years ago

Tags: gitlab, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am using spring-boot-maven-plugin with the following profile

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ci</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-info</goal>
                                    <goal>build-image</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <image>
                                        <name>${env.DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH}/core:${env.CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}</name>
                                        <publish>true</publish>
                                    </image>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

The image could be built and uploaded to gitlab. However, it is always showing Published 42 years ago.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It looks it is related to Reproduible Builds

https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#why-is-my-image-created-48-years-ago